# Where is the syntax error in my multiple table join?

Tags: mysql, join

I am attempting to write a statement to find the name of a recipe using conditions across multiple related tables, but I am getting a syntax error that reads as follows:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'quantity < 700) join ingredientlist on nutrition.recipeID = ingredientlist.reci' at line 1.

Here is the select statement I am using.

```
SELECT recipe.name 
    from recipe 
        join nutrition 
            on recipe.recipeID = nutrition.recipeID 
                AND nutrition.unit = "calories" 
                AND nutrition.quantity < 700
        join ingredientlist 
            on nutrition.recipeID = ingredientlist.recipeID 
        join ingredient 
            on ingredientlist.ingredientID = ingredient.ingredientID 
                AND ingredient.type like "fish";
```

Comment: Looks ok to me. Try replacing double quotes with single ones.

Comment: @ypercube Single and double quotes are exactly the same in MySQL. You may as well wave a rubber chicken over your computer.

Comment: SQL-query is OK, copy-pasted it to be sure and no syntax error (did get an error that the table doesn't exists in my DB, but that can only show up if the syntax is correct)

Comment: @tadman: That's only the default behaviour. "*With **[`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes)** enabled, you cannot use double quotation marks to quote literal strings, because it is interpreted as an identifier. "*

Comment: You also might be best served to move all your filtering conditions into a WHERE clause (i.e. `WHERE nutrition.unit = "calories" AND nutrition.quantity < 700 AND ingredient.type = "fish"`) Note I changed last one from LIKE to = as you really aren't even using LIKE functionality there (you have no wildcards).  That being said, your syntax looks fine, my comments were more with regards to readablity.

Comment: The single quotes actually fixed it. @tadman they should be equal, but starting and ending double quotes are viewed differently in mysql while single quotes are not as specific.

Comment: @Craig So do you have `ANSI_QUOTES` set on or off? The default behavior is MySQL does not differentiate, and I've never seen it set otherwise. Postgres strictly enforces this. Thanks to ybercube for pointing this out. If that fixed it, ybercube should add an answer.

Comment: @tadman Where can I go to check this?

Comment: @Craig: Try this: `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;`

Comment: It said STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: And `SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;` ? It seems you do not have ANSI_QUOTES enabled, so the error was not from the double quotes.

Comment: I tested your SQL statement on MySQL 5.6.13, but it didn't return any syntax error. I don't think your question is showing the statement that actually caused the error.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, double and single quotes are treated equally - to define string literals but that's not the ANSI standard and it's only the default behaviour. In the ANSI/ISO standard, the double quotes are used for column and table identifiers, not for string literals.

See the mySQL documentation:

> *With **[`ANSI_QUOTES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes)** enabled, you cannot use double quotation marks to quote literal strings, because it is interpreted as an identifier.*